# Make "Add New User" redirect to user's profile

Tags: wordpress

I'm wondering if it's possible that when you create a new user `user-new.php` you're being redirect to the user's profile instead of to `users.php`

I'm having some custom fields who only show up when you **edit** a user, so to make the workflow more easy I would like that the admin gets redirect to the user's profile so he can add those custom fields instantly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`wp_redirect` is [filterable](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L862), so you could hook in to redirect after a user was successfully added. I tested the following, might need a few tweaks but it does the trick:

```
add_filter( 'wp_redirect', 'wp_redirect_after_user_new', 1, 1 );
function wp_redirect_after_user_new( $location )
{
    global $pagenow;

    if( is_admin() && 'user-new.php' == $pagenow )
    {
        $user_details = get_user_by( 'email', $_REQUEST[ 'email' ] );
        $user_id = $user_details->ID;

        if( $location == 'users.php?update=add&id=' . $user_id )
            return add_query_arg( array( 'user_id' => $user_id ), 'user-edit.php' );
    }

    return $location;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used admin_init instead with some checks on the url parameters to see where the user came from.
But your solution seems better and works exactly the same.