# Attach media to post WordPress hook

Tags: wordpress

I need an action to be triggered when a detached media is **being attached** to a post.

It seems that this behavior is handled in [wp-admin/upload.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/upload.php#L55) on line [76](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/upload.php#L76) by setting the parent of the attachment post with a DB query. **There are no hooks in the file**.

Is there a way to get an action triggered on this event (some low level DB write hook or whatever) in which I could get the ID of the parent post to which the attachment is being attached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hook into `wp_redirect` and get the parent post ID from the `$_REQUEST`. The following is based on an answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16358609/1981996):

```
add_filter( 'wp_redirect', 'so16798615_wp_redirect', 25, 1 );
function so16798615_wp_redirect( $location )
{
    if( ! is_admin() )
        return $location;

    global $pagenow;

    if( 'upload.php' == $pagenow && isset( $_REQUEST['found_post_id'] ) )
    {
        $parent_id = (int) $_REQUEST['found_post_id'];

        if ( ! $parent_id )
            return $location;

        $parent = get_post( $parent_id );
        // do stuff with parent
    }

    return $location;
}
```